# How can i delete particular id from all the mongodb collection on click of delete button in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can i delete particular id from all the mon`your text`godb collection on click of delete button in nodejs

How can i delete particular id from all the mongodb collection on click of delete button in nodejs

Comment: Hi, no code here... Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and  [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)]

Answer (score 0):

This question is very open ended but here you go

Assuming that you are going to invoke some API endpoint

Express Endpoint

```
// You got to have Mongoose Model by the name `CollectionName`
app.delete('/api/somepath/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  CollectionName.findByIdAndDelete(id)
    .then(() => {
      // send success response
      res.send({ message: 'deleted successfully' });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // send error response
      res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error deleting', error });
    });
});
```

Mongoose Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```